# ld: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: assembly, executable, nasm, x86-64, ld

I have made a nasm assembly hello world program like this:

```
global start


section .text

start:
    mov rax, 0x20000004
    mov rdi, 1
    lea rsi, [rel msg]
    mov rdx, msg.len
    syscall

    mov rax, 0x20000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall


section .data

msg:    db  "Hello, World!", 10
.len:   equ $ - msg
```

Doing `nasm -f macho64 print.asm` does fine, but `ld -macosx_version_min 10.10 -o print print.o` gives an error like so:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

I have no idea what this means :). Could someone please help me fix this problem? Thanks! P.S. I am using a Mac with OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Probably because you need to use `_main` instead of `start` or you need to tell ld to use `start` instead of `_main`.

Comment: @RossRidge How would I do that?

Comment: I would have guessed you want `_start` with an underscore, but try `_main`, too. It is not causing this problem, but be aware there's a bad bug in Nasm-2.11.08 with `-f macho64`. Avoid that version.

Comment: I fixed it by using `_main`

Comment: I think the main problem is that you compile with default libraries. This means that the default start-up-code will be linked into your program. This code will do some initializations and then call the C function "main()".

Comment: nasm / yasm + `ld` won't link the standard libraries, unless OS X is very different from GNU `ld`.  On 64bit Linux, `GLOBAL _start` and `_start:` at the top of my stand-alone asm did the trick.  (Without that, I got a warning from `ld` that it couldn't find a `_start`, and was just going to start at `0x04000c0`, which is where `yasm` put my code's start address in the `.o`.